# Is there any tool to flatten and convert JSON schema or object in JSON format to display in plain object notation

Tags: json

I have a need to convert object in JSON format or JSON schema to something as follows:

`{
  "ArrayofObjects":[
     "Item":{
          "property":""
      }
   ]
}`

I want to convert and write it as:
 `ArrayObjects[].Item.property` 
So that I can represent the structure in one line conveying the structure of the object and talk about a property.
Actually I have two huge JSON schemas that I want to compare and talk about relation between them. I thought it is more convenient to represent them in this format  `ArrayObjects[].Item.property` side by side.
Is there any tool that can achieve the same?